# Page Width does not match Paper Size in Windows Print Dialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, printing

I am trying to print to an unusual printer (**BIXOLON SPP-R200III**) from a C# WPF application. The width of this printer's paper roll is **58mm**, as measured with a ruler and as shown in the Windows Print Dialog box:

[image: Printer Settings for the BIXOLON SPP-R200III]

However, when I try to connect to this printer and interrogate its capabilities via the `System.Printing` APIs in the .NET Framework, I get a different paper width.

The following code enumerates print queues and finds the correct one:

```
        const string printQueueName = @"BIXOLON SPP-R200III";
        PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer();
        PrintQueue printQueue = null;
        PrintQueueCollection printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues();
        foreach (PrintQueue queue in printQueues)
        {
            if (String.Equals(queue.FullName, printQueueName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                printQueue = queue;
                break;
            }
        }
```

This code interrogates its capabilities:

```
        PrintTicket defaultTicket = printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;
        PrintCapabilities printCapabilities = printQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(defaultTicket);
        double pageWidth = (printCapabilities.OrientedPageMediaWidth.Value / 96.0) * 25.4;
```

But the result, `pageWidth` is **48.047** and *not* 58mm as expected!(`PrintCapabilities.OrientedPageMediaWidth` is 181.59496062992128.)

I also tried looking at the default print-ticket structure itself but `printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width` has the same value of 181.59496062992128.

Finally, I tried to use the `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog` with the following code:

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.PrintQueue = printQueue;
        printDialog.ShowDialog();

        double pageWidth = (printDialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize.Width.Value / 96.0) * 25.4;
```

And I got the same result.

Why is this? Why do these widths not match? Am I converting from dots to millimetres incorrectly? Am I completely misunderstanding printer capabilities?

What is the right way to find the paper size supported by a printer, like it is shown in the screenshot at the top of this question?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is so called "imageble area", which is always smaller than the physical dimensions of the sheet.
Probably, your printer cannot print at the very edge of the sheet.
You can make sure by inspecting the `PrintCapabilities.PageBorderlessCapability Property`.

See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printcapabilities.pageborderlesscapability(v=vs.110).aspx

> Most laser and inkjet printers do not support borderless printing. They must allow an unprinted margin to prevent toner from getting on the parts of the printer that move the paper. Many photographic printers, however, do support borderless printing.
>   If the printer does not support borderless printing, the collection is empty.

Comment: I did think about that but `PrintCapabilities.PageBorderlessCapability` is an empty collection and `printQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.PageBorderless` is `null`, as is `printDialog.PrintTicket.PageBorderless`. This means the printer cannot support borderless printing but it gives no indication of what the border actually is. My question still stands.

Comment: A little birdy tells me that it is 5 mm.

Comment: Check the OriginWidth and OriginHeight of the PageImageableArea.